# Setting up Git to work with two different computers

Tags: git

I need to setup Git to work on several projects across two computers. I have a Macbook air, and a computer with Windows 10. I need to manage several projects between the two computers.

1. *I will not have to share my projects and either make anyone
   collaborate;*
2. *I will not work on the same time with the two
   computers.*
3. *The only thing I want is a way to work on the same projects, in
   different moments, from my Macbook Air and my Computer with Windows
   10, managing changes and the history of the projects.*

Is this possible with Git?
May anyone guide me to do this? 
​Thanks.

Comment: Version Control is the reason GIT was born; you are just going to need a remote server to act as the bridge between your two devices.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/), which is free and private for personal projects.  Won't work if you want to do this without internet access, or don't trust a third party host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is perfect for the use that you are describing. It will make it possible for you to work on several projects at once with different computers at different times, all the while having the history of all your changes on every computer.

I would suggest that you use GitHub. They have a few guides to help you get up and running, all of which can be found here: https://guides.github.com/

Bitbucket is an alternative to GitHub, and they also have guides to help you get started. You can find these here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/

They basically do the same, with a few differences in what they offer.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answering. In both there is the chance to have private projects? Or do they are public?

Comment: With bitbucket it can be free and private.  With github you can choose free *or* private, but not both.   Note: easy enough to sign up for both (for free) to test.  Create a toy repo on github if you want to experiment without sharing personal code.

Comment: On [GitHub](https://github.com/pricing) you can only have public repositories unless you have a paid account. On [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/product/pricing?tab=cloud-pricing) it is free to have private repositories.